# How do I know if I added enough detail to satisfy the "question needs details or clarity" after being closed?

Tags: support, closing-questions

I recently asked this question: [Why is the two-sample test giving me inconsistent results?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/529428/why-is-the-two-sample-test-giving-me-inconsistent-results)

It was closed afterwards and a comment was left requesting more details. I updated the question, but I'm not sure if the question is being reviewed or if even more details are needed.

How do I tell if I've addressed the reason for which this question was closed? Is there a way to see the status of the review process?

Comment: Note that your question automatically joined a review queue for potential re-opening after you edited it. So you can hope for it to be re-opened or to receive further requests for clarification.

Comment: Ah, good to know. I'll monitor for comments for additional clarification; that's where I will see the requests for further clarification, right?

Comment: The question on the main site has now been re-opened.